# Quotient rings (ring homomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. I need to show that the map $\pi: R \rightarrow R/I$ is a ring homomorphism.

I showed that it's a homomorphism under addition. But have a question on showing that it is a ring homomorphism under multiplication.

Let $a,b \in R$ define multiplication as $\pi(ab)=\bar{a}\bar{b}=ab+I$. Need to check that this is well defined.

Basically I need to show that $ (a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$ . I attempted this as follows. First I showed that $(a+I)(b+I)\subseteq ab+I$ .

But could not show that the other inclusion is hold $ab+I \subseteq (a+I)(b+I)$ to complete the proof. Any suggestions on showing this? Thanks.

Comment: But $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$ is the *definition* of the multiplication in $R/I$. Or maybe your definition of $R/I$ is by a universal property instead?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: @Michael That definition does require showing it doesn't depend on coset reps $a,b.$

Comment: Your question is a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606762/show-varphir-i-to-r-j-is-a-well-defined-ring-homomorphism) for $I=0$.

Comment: @coffeemath that's true, but this question appears to already assume $R/I$ is a ring with well-defined multiplication.